# Jquery return to parent function on button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

**I have a popup div like confirm to show like below**

```
<div class='pop'>
    check me
    <span class="spok">Ok </span>
    <span class="spcancel">cancel </span>
</div>
```

Now this popUp will be open on some condition, and on button click I want to return some values to parent function

**Button events**

```
$(".spok").click(function(){
    return 'OK';
});
$(".spcancel").click(function(){
    return 'CANCEL';
});
```

**showPop method**

```
function showpop (){
   $('.pop').show();

}
```

**now calling like this**

```
var retval = showpop()
alert(retval);
```

But it seems I am no where close to my requirement.

**Code on fiddle**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mparvez1986/gp5emrm4/)

**Update**

Able to call back the function but....
When i tried to hide the popup it alerts as many times it has been called. Select Yes or no in dropdown then after click on Ok or cancel, two or three times, you will see effect

Updated fiddle

```
[Fiddle2][2]
```

Comment: It will return the value whatever button is being clicked, please check button click event

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam you are not returning from the function but with your click events

Comment: The operation of the dialog & buttons is asynchronous. Use callbacks (e.g. passed to the dialog) or events to broadcast the result.

Comment: Can I have any link or  fiddle nearer to my scenario, that will be really helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operation of the dialog & buttons is asynchronous. Use callbacks (e.g. passed to the dialog) or events to broadcast the result. One way is to provide a callback to your popup that gets called back with the result:

```
function showpop (onclose){
   $('.pop').show();
    $(".spok").click(function(){
        onclose('OK');
    });
    $(".spcancel").click(function(){
        onclose('CANCEL');
    });   
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var retval = showpop(function(retval){
        alert(retval);
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/gp5emrm4/4/

Note: The event handlers for the click should be more specific to the dialog (probably use delegated events, attached to the popup instead):

```
function showpop (onclose){
   $('.pop').show().on('click', 'span', function(){
        onclose($(this).attr('class'));   // or some other property of the button
    });
}
```

More practical example (using `data-` attributes):

**JEFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/gp5emrm4/5/

Comment: It seems I am -0- in jquery

Comment: @Md. Parvez Alam: But now you know more than you did before. Just repeat the process daily and you will become a genius at it :)

Comment: I have one issue in this please refere http://jsfiddle.net/mparvez1986/gp5emrm4/7/   When i tried to hide the popup it alerts as many times it has been called. Select Yes or no in dropdown then after click on Ok or cancel, two or three times, you will see effect

Comment: @Md. Parvez Alam: Your new example does not make sense to me. Is the intention to select Yes or No from a drop down and then press OK/Cancel? Or something else?